# Using jquery and javascript in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript

After trying for many many days without any improvement, I think I have no other choice but to ask for your help.
I have to admit that I don't know much about coding, but I've tried various tutorials, but just can't get to work what I want.

The problem is that I want sidebar tabs using jquery tools as well as creating my own slider (no image slider, but a content slider).
Although I did just as the tutorials say, the text just is displayed normally. 
No effect, no slide, no tabs, nothing.

I uploaded the .js files, put the "script" info into the header.php, used the specific style.css, also put that into the header.php and then I tried to put some "divs" to create some content.
For the tabs I used [this tutorial](http://www.elmastudio.de/webdesign/javascript-tab-menus-coole-effekte-fur-deine-sidebar/). It's in German, but you can clearly see the steps where it tells you what to paste where. Is there anything missing? I put the "divs" into my home.php. Was that the mistake?

Do I have to put anything in my function.php as well?

I'm missing something, I'm sure of it, but I don't know what it is.
I really hope that somebody can help me out here and give me a short "step-by-step" instruction or something.

[My website](http://www.zoomingjapan.com) for reference.

Sorry for asking a stupid question, but I can't seem to sovle this by myself.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off you have way to many duplicate js files, I see at a glance 3 calls to the same jQuery in 3 separate urls, there are also other duplications (easing) and probably more that I missed, clean this up.

Secondly your not using jQuery tools properly, the javascript calls for a tab and a panel.

So remove your CSS `id's` from your content where you have them as `tabs-1`, `tabs-2` , `tabs-3`.

Just leave it empty and wrap that whole area in a `"panel" div`. It should look like this, ( you don't really have to but it's best to keep it simple and get it working first.

```
       <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="#">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="panes">

<div><p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum ......etc...</p></div>

<div><p>Morbi tincidunt........etc...</p></div>

<div><p>Mauris eleifend est et ......etc...</p></div>

</div>
```

Change your jQuery function too:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

The first part `.tabs` are you actual `li` tabs which are are in `<ul class="tabs">` and the second part `.panes` are the panels which are wrapped in `<div class="panes">`

**PS**. I forgot to add , none of this will work without the proper CSS, You can use this or incorporate it into your theme stylesheet for my example and it should work fine http://flowplayer.org/css/tabs.css

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your effort to help me out. I did what you told me, but it still doesn't work. I have this code snippet in my home.php: http://pastebin.com/hitLhtve And my header.php looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Dx9gChQT I only found one duplicate and deleted it. Still anything that I should delete? Thanks so much!

Comment: You did not add the CSS , and you have way to many js files and stylesheets.

Comment: I added the CSS in my main style.css of my theme. The js files and stylesheets have already been in the theme to begin with. Whenever I try to remove them, something in my theme stops to function :(

Comment: I cleaned up a bit more. If I delete more than that, my pop-up navigation won't work anymore. I also saw all the .css files and most of them I haven't added manually, so I suppose they're all plugin .css files.

Comment: Hello again. I tried again and I have a question: Do I have to replace the "#" in the link tag or should that be generated automatically? Because right now, it's not.

Comment: The `#` is a placeholder for the HTML link tag, you have to add your link manually or dynamically with a function. http://w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Thanks so much. It still doesn't display the text as tabs. I suspect that I'm not implementing the jquery-ui correctly. My function.php: `function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
 wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('custom');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.form');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');`